# how to store variable in background page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am developing Google Chrome Extension. I want to maintain state of user. if any user logged in then after page refresh he/she should be logged in. how can i maintain this type of state.

Comment: You can use session of application for it. If you are using any server-side code then it'll be more easier. search for it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Background Pages store value till session of browser, if you are looking for a stable storage use Chrome.storage. You can take following code as reference.

## Demonstration

#### manifest.json

Registered background page with chrome extension

```
{
    "name": "Persist Value",
    "description": "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14744916/how-to-store-variable-in-background-page",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "version": "1",
    "permissions": [
        "storage"
    ],
    "background": {
        "scripts": [
            "background.js"
        ]
    }
}
```

#### background.js

Some trivial implementation.

```
//You can use Storage API
chrome.storage.local.set({
    "Name": "Your_variable",
    "Value": "Some Value"
}, function () {
    console.log("Storage Succesful");
});
```

## References

- [Storage API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage.html)

Comment: is this storage mechanism secure? means other then extension any one can access this storage ?

Comment: No, this is completely sand-boxed and secure

Answer (score 0):

In your case it sounds like you mean to save the state of the user on a server side , which is a big difference from saving state on the extension itself . 
For example - you may have some server-side code (written in PHP or whatever other server-side language) that keeps track of your chrome extension users whenever they log in. For that -  "sessions" are very common and good and are implemented and probably all server-side languages. If this is what you are looking for it's best to read about server-side programming and ajax before delving into your extension.

However , if you want to save state on your chrome extension 'locally' (without involving a server) then html5's localStorage is a good option http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html.

Answer (score 0):

You can store you variables to `localStorage` using follow methods: `localStorage.setItem()`, `localStorage.getItem()`, but localStorage has limits

If you gave big data use `chrome.storage.local` or `chrome.storage.sync`

localStorage works fasten then chrome.storage and chrome.storage is asynchronous